# PXE booting / TFTP/DHCP issue (using Cobbler 2.0)

Tags: pxe-boot, cobbler, tftp

I'm using Cobbler 2.x from the EPEL repositories.  Have used 1.6 for ages.

I've imported the CentOS 5.5 DVD (also tried this with 5.4).  The DVD imports with no apparent issue, and sets up the standard and xen kernel distros.  If I build a system and provision it with the standard kernel it works perfectly.

However, if I build a system and provision it with the xen kernel, the process fails while trying to download the stage 1 kernel.

from syslog w/tftp -vvv logging enabled.

```
Sep 25 02:04:08 sfo-util-01 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:25:90:19:4c:21 via bond0
Sep 25 02:04:09 sfo-util-01 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.180.254 to 00:25:90:19:4c:21 via bond0
Sep 25 02:04:10 sfo-util-01 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.180.254 (192.168.180.10) from 00:25:90:19:4c:21 via bond0
Sep 25 02:04:10 sfo-util-01 dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.180.254 to 00:25:90:19:4c:21 via bond0
Sep 25 02:04:10 sfo-util-01 in.tftpd[12698]: RRQ from 192.168.180.254 filename /pxelinux.0 
Sep 25 02:04:10 sfo-util-01 in.tftpd[12698]: tftp: client does not accept options 
Sep 25 02:04:10 sfo-util-01 in.tftpd[12699]: RRQ from 192.168.180.254 filename /pxelinux.0 
Sep 25 02:04:10 sfo-util-01 in.tftpd[12700]: RRQ from 192.168.180.254 filename /pxelinux.cfg/20c11ca6-ed20-3398-0ec6-002590194c22 
Sep 25 02:04:10 sfo-util-01 in.tftpd[12701]: RRQ from 192.168.180.254 filename /pxelinux.cfg/01-00-25-90-19-4c-21 
Sep 25 02:04:10 sfo-util-01 in.tftpd[12702]: RRQ from 192.168.180.254 filename //images/centos5.5-xen-x86_64/vmlinuz 
Sep 25 02:04:10 sfo-util-01 in.tftpd[12703]: RRQ from 192.168.180.254 filename //images/centos5.5-xen-x86_64/vmlinuz 
Sep 25 02:04:10 sfo-util-01 in.tftpd[12704]: RRQ from 192.168.180.254 filename //images/centos5.5-xen-x86_64/vmlinuz 
Sep 25 02:04:10 sfo-util-01 in.tftpd[12705]: RRQ from 192.168.180.254 filename //images/centos5.5-xen-x86_64/vmlinuz 
Sep 25 02:04:10 sfo-util-01 in.tftpd[12706]: RRQ from 192.168.180.254 filename //images/centos5.5-xen-x86_64/vmlinuz 
Sep 25 02:04:10 sfo-util-01 in.tftpd[12707]: RRQ from 192.168.180.254 filename //images/centos5.5-xen-x86_64/vmlinuz 
Sep 25 02:04:10 sfo-util-01 in.tftpd[12708]: RRQ from 192.168.180.254 filename //images/centos5.5-xen-x86_64/vmlinuz 
Sep 25 02:04:10 sfo-util-01 in.tftpd[12709]: RRQ from 192.168.180.254 filename //images/centos5.5-xen-x86_64/vmlinuz
```

for this particular system my pxelinux.cfg is:

```
default linux
prompt 0
timeout 1
label linux
        kernel /images/centos5.5-xen-x86_64/vmlinuz
        ipappend 2
        append initrd=/images/centos5.5-xen-x86_64/initrd.img ksdevice=bootif lang=  kssendmac text  ks=http://192.168.180.10/cblr/svc/op/ks/system/sfo-virt-01
```

I've quintuple-checked the paths that are requested and everything exists and is available over the network.  I've been beating my head over this for over a day and any insight would be incredibly appreciated.  I've md5sum'd everything I can think of and am totally without ideas at this point.

Thanks.

Comment: Did it ever work?

Answer (score 1):

Try transferring the files over tftp:

```
[random-box]$ tftp sfo-util-01
get /pxelinux.0
get /pxelinux.cfg/01-00-25-90-19-4c-21
get //images/centos5.5-xen-x86_64/vmlinuz
```

My guess from the looks of the retries in the log is that in the manual test you on't be able to get the `vmlinuz` file, due to the double slash.

Try:

```
kernel images/centos5.5-xen-x86_64/vmlinuz
```

And then test via manual tftp calls.